# Convert ActiveRecord query to PostgreSQL query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I am trying to update this piece of rails code into raw PostgreSQL

```
ValidationEmergency.with_deleted.where(
  code: 'aml_validation_failed', 
  service_name: 'ComplyAdvantage', service_type: nil).each do |e|
    e.update_attributes(
      {
        service_type: 'Screening',
        service_id:   e.message.split(', ').last.split(' => ').last.to_i
      }, without_protection: true
    )
  end
```

what I have so far (edited after @fanta's comment)

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("
  UPDATE validation_emergencies 
  SET 
    service_type = 'Screening', 
    service_id = (
      CAST ( array_upper(string_to_array(message, ' => '), 1) AS INTEGER )
    ) 
  WHERE 
    code = 'aml_validation_failed' 
  AND 
    service_name = 'ComplyAdvantage' 
  AND 
    service_type IS NULL"
)
```

Service type is being updated properly, but the service_id is not, still looking into how to properly split and gsub with postgresql.

Please advise. Thank you.

Comment: your `IN` is wrong, but before that, why do you need the `IN` ?, you're updating the same table, no joins, etc. Just do `UPDATE validation_emergencies ... WHERE code = 'aml_validation_failed' AND service_name = 'ComplyAdvantage' AND service_type IS NULL`

Comment: @fanta thanks, you are right about that. However, I am more concerned about `(array_upper(string_to_array(message, ', '), 1))` how to split, and gsub and get the integet out of a message like this `"exception_message => Japan user, POA confirmation required. Comply Advantage API screening 0 positive hits, screening_id => 329"`, I am looking to get the 329 into service_id field

Comment: split by `=>` like `(array_upper(string_to_array(message, '=> '), 1))`

Comment: @fanta splitting by => is definitely a great idea.. I kind of forgot I can split a string by any character, not `,` only.
I am doing also cast to INTGER for the value that is returned by split.
`UPDATE validation_emergencies SET service_type = 'Screening', service_id = CAST ((array_upper(string_to_array(message, ' => '), 1)) AS INTEGER) WHERE code = 'aml_validation_failed' AND service_name = 'ComplyAdvantage' and service_type IS NULL`
but in the end I still get wrong service_id
`[4, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2` when it should be `[287, 329, 331, 352, 381, 411, 413, 438, 439, 443, 444, 446]`. ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Final version, for service_id it will split the message, get the last element and cast it to integer.

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(
  "UPDATE validation_emergencies
   SET
     service_type = 'Screening',
     service_id =
       CAST ((string_to_array(message, ' => '))[array_upper(string_to_array(message, ' => '), 1)] AS INTEGER)
   WHERE
     code = 'aml_validation_failed'
   AND
     service_name = 'ComplyAdvantage'
   AND
     service_type IS NULL"
)
```